# A problem on finding cap product structure on $\mathbb {RP}^{2}$ and Klein's bottle .

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space, klein-bottle

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Compute all the cap products for $\mathbb{RP}^{2}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} / 2$ coefficients. Do the same for the Klein's bottle $K$.

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ As $H_{0}(\mathbb {RP}^{2};\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z$ and $H_{1}(\mathbb {RP}^{2};\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z_{2}$ and rest homology groups are $0.$

Then for $\mathbb {RP}^{2}$ ,
we only need to find :

$H_{0}(M) × H^{0}(M) \to H_{0}(M)$
and
$H_{1}(M) × H^{1}(M) \to H_{0}(M)$

where $M=\mathbb {RP}^{2}$

The simplicial complex is : [image]

But, I can't figure out how to start calculating it and also for $\mathbb Z_{2}$ co-efficients .

And, I also couldn't do anything with $K.$

$H_{0}({K};\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z$ and $H_{1}({K};\mathbb Z)= \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_{2}.$ and rest are $0.$

Hence we only have to find :

$H_{0}(M) × H^{0}(M) \to H_{0}(M)$
and
$H_{1}(M) × H^{1}(M) \to H_{0}(M)$

where $M=K.$

The simplicial complex is :[image]

A help is much needed, thanks in advance .

Comment: What about $\frown : H_1(M) \times H^0(M) \to H_1(M)$?

Comment: When $k=l$, then $\frown : H_k(M) \times H^k(M) \to H_0(M)$ is just evaluation map $(\sigma, \varphi) \mapsto \varphi(\sigma)$.

Comment: Yes but how to evaluate it in the case $k=l ?$